Star Trek TNG: Did we ever actually see the Enterprise's computer?
Is there a HAL 9000 room somewhere on the Enterprise-D?
It's probably Majel Barrett sitting in a chair on the holodeck with the Barclay intelligence hat on.

Yes.
According to the Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual, the USS Enterprise-D has three computer cores; two located near the centre of the primary hull (AKA the saucer section) and one in the engineering hull (AKA the drive section).

The heart of the main computer system is a set of three redundant main processing cores. Any of these three cores is able to handle the primary operational load of the entire vessel. Two of these cores are located near the center of the Primary Hull between Decks 5 and 14, while the third is located between Decks 30 and 37 in the Engineering Hull.
Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual - page 49

One of the computer cores was shown on-screen in TNG S03E01, "Evolution." The text quoted below is from the Memory Alpha page for the episode.

Dr. Stubbs has now gone down to the computer core, where Data, La Forge and Wesley are working. After climbing down an access ladder to join them, Stubbs learns from Crusher that he, Data, and La Forge are trying low gamma bursts in an effort to slow down the productivity of the nanites. Stubbs asks if they have tried a high-level charge but Data replies a high-level charge will kill them. "I know," Stubbs says, taking out an energy weapon and firing on the core with high-intensity gamma radiation. Data, La Forge and Wesley grab the doctor, stopping him before he can do any more damage.

Picard, Riker, Worf, Data, and Stubbs are now down in the computer core, where Data is making preparations for the transfer. He places his hand on a piece of equipment and the nanites enter his body. His head suddenly jerks up and haltingly looks around, as the nanites experience the world as Data does for the first time.




Star Trek: The Next Generation - S03E01 - "Evolution"

